# Does an empty [if IE] improve site performance?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I was digging around on some HTML on a webpage and saw this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<!--[if IE]><![endif]--><!--Empty IE conditional comment to improve site performance-->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
```

Does having an empty IE conditional really improve a site's performance? What does it do to improve performance?

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't make since to me either. But IE is pretty weird so I don't know

Comment: @JohnConde It's a secret hax. (I doubt it, but... oddball question so +1.)

Comment: That comment is an obvious joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some online articles, **IT DOES** if you have a IE conditional css to load.
See http://www.phpied.com/conditional-comments-block-downloads/

If you have this in your page, for example:

```
<!--[if IE 6 ]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"
      href="styles/ie6.css">
<![endif]-->
```

It will block further download before the main CSS is loaded.

If you add this at the start of the page:

```
<!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
```

This will not happen.

**P.S. I am really surprised when I read the article. So that's a joke of IE.**

Comment: Was about to post link after reading. Very interesting results.